# How to merge two files line by line in shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sh

I would like to merge two input files resulting on the first file plus the content of the second file that's not duplicated (only considering the first parameter separated by comma) . How can I implement this in a .sh? Here is the sample data as below. Thank you

What I have

```
file1            file2
1,A               1,B   
2,B               2,B   
3,C               4,B
                  5,D
```

Desired Output

```
file1
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,B
5,D
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. SO is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Awk is well-sorted for this type of thing

```
$ awk -F',' '!a[$1]++' file1 file2
1,A
2,B
3,C
4,B
5,D
```

#### Explanation

- `-F','`  Use a comma as the field separators
- `!a[$1]++` Shortcut for *if you have never seen field #1 before, print the whole line*

Comment: Nice answer, feels somewhat like https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ : ) For that matter: you can save two bytes as `,` does not require quoting. `awk -F, ...` is ok too.

Comment: Works perfectly :) thanks

Comment: @oguzismail Take your +1

Answer (score 0):

Since the question doesn't clearly exclude such techniques, here is another way to do it:

```
sort file1 file2
```

The `sort` utility merges files and sorts the result, in the case of the above, outputting to stdout.

Comment: `sort` (at least as-written) will double up the lines rather than prefer instances from file1

Comment: I think it's a little more complicated with sort and GNU uniq: `awk -F ',' '{print $2,$1}' file1 file2 | sort | uniq -f 1 | awk -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$1}' | sort`